# НасыщеННа или насыщеНа?

Tags: орфография, нн, краткое-причастие, краткое-прилагательное

*Жизнь главной героини **насыщенна** и полна сюрпризов.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно с двумя Н:
*Жизнь главной героини насыще**нн**а и полна сюрпризов.*
В данном случае это краткое прилагательное.

При наличии зависимых слов – причастие (одна Н):
*Жизнь главной героини насыще**н**а сюрпризами.*

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса:
*В 1909 жизнь Габриэль Мюнтер была чрезвычайно насыще**нн**а.*
*Хочется отметить, что политическая жизнь в Монголии очень насыще**нн**а.*

*Жизнь насыще**н**а множеством ценных идей...*
*...вся жизнь насыще**н**а ежечасными влияниями школ, теорий, приемов...*

[Буквы ***нн*** и ***н*** в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62) (Розенталь):

> 7. В кратких формах страдательных причастий пишется одно *н*. В кратких отглагольных прилагательных (как и в отыменных) сохраняется написание **нн**. Отглагольные прилагательные отвечают на вопрос «каков?» («какова?», «каково?», «каковы?»). Ср.:
>    *Мировая общественность была **взволнована** сообщениями о гибели космонавтов.
>
>    Игра актёра была проникновенна и **взволнованна.***

Comment: Саша, посмотрите, пожалуйста, на примеры из Нацкорпуса с -нн-. Мне они *показались* ошибочными. Рассуждения мои в комментарий никак не влезали, поэтому пришлось изобразить ответ. Или это я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 4):

Я все-таки добавлю еще один ответ по этой теме.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 06.10.2022**

Итак, речь идет о **«нестандартности»** парного варианта причастия и прилагательного для слова **«насыщенный».**

Напомню, как различаются **стандартные пары** этой группы слов, обозначенной Розенталем в п.7. Прилагательные  в этой группе можно определить по прямому или переносному значению даже **при отсутствии** зависимых слов.

(1) **Причастие**  определяется по следующим признакам: обозначает признак по действию; имеет прямое, а не переносное  значение; можно подобрать зависимое слово в Т. п. со значением производителя или орудия действия.

(2) **Прилагательное** определяется по следующим признакам: обозначает качественный признак, отвечает на вопрос «каков»; имеет переносное, а не прямое  значение; можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным; возможны однородные отношения с другими прилагательными.

Признак **по действию или качеству** сохраняется и для слова «насыщенный», но есть существенная разница по отношению **к зависимым словам.** Дело в том, что в этом случае причастие и прилагательное **не различаются** по переносному и прямому значению, поэтому **способ их определения** в краткой форме указан в **ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКОМ СЛОВАРЕ**:

**насыщенный**; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (**с дополн.**: жизнь насыщена приключениями) и -ен, -енна (**без дополн**.: жизнь насыщенна, содержательна).

Из словаря следует, что **формальные признаки** очень существенны. При наличии зависимых слов это **причастие**, а при их отсутствии это **прилагательное**. Но сохраняется признак по отношению к однородному ряду прилагательных.

Очевидно, что **наречия степени в качестве усилительных слов** (очень, чрезвычайно) относятся также к прилагательным. **В Нацкорпусе** в большинстве случаев НН пишется при наличии усилительных слов, а Н – при наличии зависимых слов в Т.п.

**НАСЫТИТЬ,** св. 1. кого-что. 3. обычно страд. прич. прош. Наполнить, преисполнить чем-л.; снабдить в изобилии. Жизнь насыщена до предела.

**НАСЫЩЕННЫЙ,** 2. Очень содержательный, богатый чем-л. Н-ая информация. Н-ое сообщение. Н-ая жизнь.

**Еще одно дополнение.** Интересно **сравнить два варианта**:

(1) *Жизнь **насыщенна** и полна сюрпризов* (прилагательное, НН).

(2) *Жизнь **насыщена** (= заполнена) **до предела** и полна сюрпризов* (причастие, Н).

И вот **графика** второго варианта (с причастием) выглядит **лучше** (однозначнее). В этом случае  при первом прочтении не возникает желания отнести слово "сюрпризов/сюрпризами" к обоим однородным сказуемым, как в первом варианте.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что стоит обратить внимание на пятый пункт правил Розенталя.

> Два н (нн) пишется в бесприставочных причастиях, образованных от глаголов совершенного вида: *броше**нн**ый, да**нн**ый, купле**нн**ый, лишё**нн**ый,
> пленё**нн**ый* и др...

Это напрямую относится к нашему вопросу, потому что слово **насыщенный** в зависимости от контекста может выступать и полным страдательным причастием, и отглагольным прилагательным.
Но в данном случае правописание не зависит от того, к какой из двух частей речи относится слово — они оба образованы от глагола совершенного вида "насытить" (что сделать?), поэтому их нужно писать с удвоенной "н" (-нн-).

И еще мне кажется, что в примерах Александра из Нацкорпуса присутствуют ошибки.
Думаю, что правильно надо писать с одной "н", так как имеются зависимые слова (наречия):
*В 1909 жизнь Габриэль Мюнтер была **чрезвычайно** насыще**н**а.

Хочется отметить, что политическая жизнь в Монголии **очень** насыще**н**а.*

Предлагаю другой пример:
*Наша жизнь была **насыщенна**: ходили почти на все премьеры в кино, театры, путешествовали по стране, бывали за границей* ([из статьи](http://jf.spbu.ru/graduate/1095/5522.html)).

Для сравнения:
Программа культурного мероприятия была насыще**нн**а и интересна.
Последняя неделя января была насыще**н**а разными событиями.
Концертная программа была очень насыще**н**а.

Comment: Нет, вы ошибаетесь. Эти наречия усиливают качество. Эти слова не превращают в причастие, потому что прилагательные также употребляются с такими наречиями. Превращают тогда, когда замена на чистое прилагательное (другое слово) невозможна из-за зависимых слов. Так же и когда "не" с причастиями.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже сначала хотела добавить комментарий к первому ответу, но теперь дам свой ответ.

Я полагаю, что первый ответ, а также все примеры в нем **верные**. Эта тема действительно относится **к п.7 правил Розенталя**, но объяснение, как я думаю, нужно **дополнить**.

А это уже готовый **комментарий**, который был подготовлен до второго ответа.

Александр, а как объяснить **разное написание** предложений: *Жизнь **насыщена** до предела* (из словаря Кузнецова). *Жизнь чрезвычайно **насыщенна**.*

Смысл вроде бы один и тот же (полнота признака). Но обычно эти пары отличаются **по семантике** даже без наличия зависимых слов, например:

Люди ***взволнованы***, их лица ***взволнованны.*** На свете чудеса **рассеяны** повсюду. Ах, король, как **рассеянны** Вы.

Здесь хорошо видно **переносное значение** прилагательных (нельзя взволновать лицо). А эта пара мне кажется **нестандартной**, хотя она из той же темы. Достаточно ли в данном случае ссылки на п.7. Розенталя?

Я не сомневаюсь в правильности вашего выбора, но мне интересно узнать ваше мнение. **Версия ответа** (дополнения к п.7) у меня есть, и я добавлю ее, если не будет комментариев.

Comment: Напишу обязательно, и Римме тоже. Только до позднего вечера очень некогда.

Comment: Спасибо. Разные мнения – это всегда интересно, на то он и форум. А я добавлю дополнение (очень короткое) завтра.

Comment: К сожалению, форум так и не состоялся, а мне не досталось ни одного комментария. Одни отметочки – прочитано. но ни критики, ни одобрения.  Что ж, и на этом спасибо. Скорее всего, всё сказанное непонятно, неинтересно и никому не нужно.

Comment: Форум не состоялся, не до него было, простите! Но я одобряю ваш сегодняшний ответ и вчерашний ответ-комментарий. Всё сказанное понятно, интересно и нужно!  А написать я хотел то же самое, прям слово в слово :)) о признаках, качествах, наречиях и пр. Спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрел, они ссылаются на ПАС.  Кажется, что контекста не хватает, хотя... А разве "равноценно" не наречие степени?  Какое-то двоякое ощущение у меня: и так, и так нормально :)) Надо покрутить подольше...  О, а зачем вы удалили комментарий?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Александр, а можно еще вопрос по теме. Н или НН в таком предложении: С точки зрения переживаемых эмоций все три линии были равноценно насыщены (насыщенны). Меня удивило предлагаемое решение одной корректорской фирмы. А вы как думаете? Явных подсказок нет: ни наречий степени, ни Т.п.   ПАС дает общее решение, а здесь нужен индивидуальный подход. В орфографическом словаре ясно всё написано.

Comment: Сейчас верну, я думала, вы не видели, а мне хотелось сразу переговорить. На наречие степени совсем не похоже (они обозначают полноту действия). Думаю, что это обстоятельство образа действия: насытили (как?) равномерно. Там даже глагол "были" есть. А как вам нравится их тупое объяснение – просто использовали формальную схему на все случаи жизни. Заглянуть в словарь им и в голову не приходит. Значит, ПАС сюда не подходит, Грамота.ру четко придерживается правила о наречиях степени и Т.п. Но здесь вот особый случай.  Тогда завтра договорим.