# Девушка надёжна и проверенна или девушка надёжна и проверена

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия, нн

Возможно ли в данном контексте из-за взаимосвязи слов "надёжна и проверен(н)а" и их сочетаемости посчитать оба эти слова краткими прилагательными и написать "проверен(н)а" с двумя нн?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**МОЙ ВАРИАНТ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ**: *Девушка надежна, **проверена** в деле.*

Вариант "***Девушка надежна и проверена***" стилистически некорректен, так как в **КРАТКОЙ** форме можно увидеть **прямое** значение причастия. Так и хочется спросить о наличии письменного **сертификата качества**.

В тоже время возможен вариант с полной формой: **Девушка надежная и проверенная.**

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. **Однородные отношения?**  Да, это однородные краткие **прилагательные**. Значение у глагольной формы переносное. Суффикс ***ЕН***, а не ***ЕНН*** пишется в соответствии **со словарем:**

Русский орфографический словарь: ***проверенный***; кр. ф. **-ен, -ена**

Большой толковый словарь русского языка

***ПРОВЕРЕННЫЙ,*** -ая, -ое. Доказавший на практике наличие нужных качеств; **испытанный**. П. работник. **Свой** человек, п.! П-ая технология. П. препарат. П-ые методы лечения.

2. Значения глагола ***проверить*** и причастия ***проверенный*** другие (**целенаправленная** проверка):
   (1) Установить правильность или ошибочность чего-л. (2) Обследовать с целью надзора, контроля.  (3) Подвергнуть испытанию для выяснения качеств, свойств, знаний, пригодности к чему-л. и т.п.

Можно проверить **знания учеников,** а не самих учеников. Поэтому в сочетании "проверенный (свой, надежный) человек" значение у прилагательного не прямое, а переносное.

3. Правильность орфографического словаря РАН подтверждает **практика:** формы ***проверенна***, ***проверенны*** единичны, да и выглядят некорректно. В большинстве случаев используется формы с ***ЕН*** как для **причастий**, так и для **прилагательных.**

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

**Причастия**

Слышал я, впрочем, что подлинность вещей была потом **проверена** чрез многих знакомых и родных убитой и что сомнений в том не было (Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы, 1880)

А к четырем часам утра бумага была напечатана, **проверена** и отложена в особую папку с надписью: " На визу

**Прилагательные**

Сомнений в выборе транспортного средства не было: «восьмерка» 1987 года выпуска многократно **проверена в деле**, надежна и хорошо оборудована:

**Некорректно**

Соответственно, этот понятийный аппарат может быть расшифрован, а обнаруженные знания **проверенны** опытным путём.

...это старые народные методы, они ***проверенны*** годами.

Наша рассылочная система **проверенна** временем и действует безотказно!

Comment: Таким образом, получается, что даже если причастие имеет переносное значение и выступает в качестве прилагательного, это не всегда означает написание его краткой формы по правилам для прилагательных, и требуется всегда сверяться со словарём.

Comment: Спасибо, Иван, за вопрос.  Я чуть позже напишу про словари в поле ответа.

Answer (score 2):

**Как работать со словарями** в теме "Н и НН в кратких причастиях и прилагательных"

Я не сразу определилась в этой теме, но в настоящий момент действую так.

1. **Словарь РАН** и толковый словарь **Кузнецова** на сайте [Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71&dicts%5B%5D=42)

Русский орфографический словарь:
**проверенный**; кр. ф. -ен, -ена.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка:
**ПРОВЕРЕННЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. Доказавший на практике наличие нужных качеств; испытанный. П. работник. Свой человек, п.! П-ая технология. П. препарат. П-ые методы лечения.

В толковом словаре указана статья **для прилагательного** с переносным значением. В словаре РАН информация также дается для **прилагательного**.  Делаем вывод: **кр. ф. -ен, -ена.**

У причастия также: кр. ф. **-ен, -ена**. Выбирать нечего.

2. Почему в кратком прилагательном пишется **одна буква Н?** Прилагательное имеет **переносное** значение, но ведет себя **как причастие.** О таких прилагательных говорится: [Розенталь §48, пункт 7 и 8](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62); ПАС под ред.Лопатина § 102.

**п.7. Примечание.** Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — с одним н, **подобно причастиям,** с которыми их сближает **наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола:** заплаканные глаза — глаза заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; поношенное платье — платье поношено. **п. 8.** Некоторые прилагательные допускают **двоякое написание краткой формы** в зависимости от значения и **конструкции**.

3. Итак, краткие прилагательные можно разделить **на 3 группы:** (1)  всегда -енна; (2) всегда -ена; () -енна или -ена в зависимости от конструкции. Понятное дело, что написание таких прилагательные вызывает у пользователей **значительные трудности.** Решить проблему можно только с помощью **словаря РАН.** С него всегда и начинаем.
4. Также приходится смотреть словарную статью для глагола ***проверить***, чтобы определить прямое значение **причастия**. А **переносное** значение прилагательного противопоставлено  этому значению.

**Примеры:**

**Пример 1. Насыщена или насыщенна?**  **[Форум.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472349/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%9D%D0%B0)**

**Русский орфографический словарь:** насыщенный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (**с дополн.**: жизнь насыщена приключениями) и -ен, -енна (**без дополн**.: жизнь насыщенна, содержательна)

При наличии дополнения краткое прилагательное ведет себя как причастие (Н), а без дополнения — как прилагательное (НН).

**Пример 2. Оправдана или оправданна?**

**Русский орфографический словарь:**
оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана (**с дополн.:** оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (**без дополн.**: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)

**[И форум:](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/479995/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC/480003#comment522206_480003)** Все способы борьбы **оправданны**))  Минусовки, обращение к автору и т.д.

Comment: Как всегда очень обстоятельно и мотивированно.)

Comment: Спасибо!  Вы меня вдохновляете)  // Надо было подвести итог работы за 1 год и 5 месяцев. Тогда  (7 октября 2022 года, насыщенна или насыщена?) всё было еще недостаточно ясно.  // А в Сети  до сих пор  ответов про "оправда(Н)На" – воз и маленькая тележка https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=13005  Вот такая это непростая тема.

Comment: Ваше структурированное обоснование ответа, практически не оставляет каких-либо неясностей в этом вопросе, особенно с опорой на словарь РАН. Три категории + словарная статья исключают какие бы то ни было тёмные пятна.)

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Вы же видели дискуссию. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/479995/Газетный-спор-о-насущном/480003#comment522206_480003  Словари никого не убедили: пользователи не понимают важности словарей или не умеют их читать.  А правила прочитали когда-то, да и то в общих чертах. // Но при этом каждый уверен в правильности своего мнения. Вот такая у нас логика жизни))

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть статью на тему  https://proza.ru/2022/12/10/1768

Comment: Статья хорошая, но мне кажется, что она нуждается в редакционной правке в разделе "Группа 1".)

Comment: Спасибо, текст исправлен.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего корректно только "проверена", потому что проверенна, от проверенная, от провенный - то есть некоторое качество, например - проверенный маршрут. Тут, однако, нужно заметить, что маршрут - это что-то не одушевлённое. В этом смысле, проверенный педагог будет означать - что человек обладает проверенными педагогическими знаниями, а что может значить "проверенная девушка" - какое-то проверенное качество девушки, девственность? я даже теряюсь, что можно проверять у девушек. Ну если проверяли на половую принадлежность, но наверное, можно сказать "проверенная", тогда - надёжная и проверенная. Если же проверенность не касается каких-то девичьих качеств, то тогда лучше сказать: "эта девушка как товарищ надёжная и проверенная".

Кроме того имеет быть тавтология, так как надёжная = проверенная.

Comment: Когда говорят: проверенные люди, то как их проверяют?

Comment: Проверенные, значит "надёжные", которые прошли проверку и стали обладать качеством проверенности. Проверенные они не потому что они люди, а потому что проверенные по каком-то виду деятельности, поэтому корректно указать вид деятельности, к которому относится проверка, ну или область применения проверки. Тут нужно контекст смотреть.

Comment: Разве непонятно, о какой деятельности говорится? Что-нибудь криминальное, где нужны проверенные люди.  Здесь синонимичные прилагательные: надежный, проверенный.

Comment: @Sharon Ну почему же сразу криминальное?) Вполне вероятно, что речь может идти о разведке в годы ВОВ.

Comment: @Sharon я подумаю)

Comment: @Иван Романов - "девушка", вряд так ли называли в годы ВОВ. Вообще сочетание "девушка ... проверена/-нна/-нная" с расстоянием до 10 слов на нацкопрусе не встречается.) Потому что у девушки проверять можно не так много)

Comment: @Буратино  Нужен контекст, а то так не разобраться?)  С девушками-товарищами?

Comment: @Иван Романов  Как-то странно звучит: надежна и проверена.  Стиль некорректный.

Comment: @Буратино Как минимум у девушки, которую забрасывают с разведывательно-диверсионной группой в глубокий вражеский тыл, должны быть проверены морально-волевые качества.

Comment: @Sharon Вполне возможно, что звучит немного странно. Давайте опустим союз "и" и просто поставим запятую

Comment: @ИванРоманов  Слово "девушка" не подходит. Ну да ладно, вот фраза - " проверенный и серьезный взгляд" или "взгляд серьёзный и проверенный", "взгляд серьёзен и проверенный?" - нет, "взгляд серьёзен и проверен", либо "взгляд серьёзен и автомат проверенный" - но тогда это союз между "взгляд и автомат." А почему так, надо подумать) Хотя можно "взгляд провенный серьёзен".

Comment: @ИванРоманов Все-таки нет, стиль для краткой формы не подходит. Я могу согласиться на такой вариант: девушка надежная, проверенная.

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса; "Надежны и проверены практикой, но любые странности в работе должны подвигнуть вас к подробной диагностике". Моя диагностика такая: нашей девушке не хватает зависимого слова. Девушка надежна, проверена в деле.